# Photo Gallery Screensaver

Tags: screensaver

How can I set up a screensaver to randomly display images from one folder from the harddrive. This was extremely easy in Windows, but I can't figure out how to set it up in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pictures inside Pictures folder as screensaver. Just Choose Pictures Folder in your screensaver preferences.

[image]

For any other folder I think [this](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/6414/) is what you should look into.